# couple will find $2$ adjacent empty seat for them

Tags: probability

> There are $10$ empty seats in a row in a show. $6$ people sit randomly on them. Then find the probability that a couple will find $2$ adjacent empty seat for them, is

what i try

Total number of ways $\displaystyle =\binom{10}{6}$

I am trying to find number of ways in which no  two adjacent seat for them and subtract that probability from $1$

But did not understand how can i find. Help me please

Comment: Consider rather the number of ways to distribute the *empty* seats, $\binom{10}{4}$

Answer (score 4):

To find the number of ways where no 2 empty seats are beside each other, you may proceed as follows:

- Take the $4$ empty seats $E,E,E,E$ and put at least one taken seat $T$ in between: $|E|T|E|T|E|T|E|$
- Now you have 3 taken seats left to be distribute over 5 possible places:
  $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 3$$

So, you get $\binom{3+4}{4}=35$ possible way with **no two EMPTY seats beside each other**.

So,

$$P\left(\text{couple finds 2 neighbouring seats}\right)= 1- \frac{\binom{7}{4}}{\binom{10}{6}}= \frac 56$$

You can also see it as finding all sequences of length $10$ consisting of four $0$s and six $1$s where no two $0$s are beside each other. So, there is always at least a $1$ between two $0$s.